# How to create a customize primary constructor of sub data-class in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, abstract-class, dto, data-class

I have a class structure like below:

```
abstract class AuthorizeSalesRequestDto {
    open val sequenceNumber: Int = 0
    open val currentService: String = ""
    open val amount: Int = 0
    open val taxOthers: Int = 0
    open val trainingMode: Boolean = false
}

data class CreditAuthorizeSales(
        override val currentService: String = "Credit"
) : AuthorizeSalesRequestDto() {

}

data class UnionPayAuthorizeSales(
        override val currentService: String = "UnionPay"
) : AuthorizeSalesRequestDto() {

}
```

I want to init the CreditAuthorizeSales and UnionPayAuthorizeSales like below:

```
val creditObject = CreditPayment(
        sequenceNumber = 1,
        amount = 100,
        taxOthers = 10,
        trainingMode = true
)
```

I create class structure because future will be more data class like CreditAuthorizeSales for different service. But I can't figure out a way to make a constructor like above.
Can somebody please help me with the syntax or change the class structure? Thanks in advace!!!

Note: Enviroment

- Kotlin v1.4.3

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? None of the properties in `AuthorizeSalesRequestDto` except `currentService` will be used to generate the `equals`, `hashCode`, and other useful methods in `CreditAuthorizeSales`. And since when is there a Kotlin 3.5? The latest version is 1.5.x as far as I know. Anyway, it seems like you are overusing inheritance. Do you _really_ need `CreditAuthorizeSales` and `UnionPayAuthorizeSales`? How about just make `AuthorizeSalesRequestDto` a data class, and use a factory to produce objects with different `currentService`?

Comment: @Sweeper yeah i think your idea seem better but because these class will be used also in difference module code so it is important to make these dto class to become seprate class.

Comment: @Sweeper Can you please explain more about "None of the properties in AuthorizeSalesRequestDto except currentService will be used to generate the equals, hashCode, and other useful methods in CreditAuthorizeSales" ?

Comment: You know that [data classes](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/data-classes.html) will have `equals` and `hashCode` and other useful methods automatically generated, right? The generated methods will only use the properties that you put in the primary constructor, in this case, `currentService`, and not any of the properties in the superclass.

Comment: @Sweeper I know that but i thought that the primary constructor of CreditAuthorizeSales will call constructor of AuthorizeSalesRequestDto and it still going to be generated?